# Simulate an unfair die

Tags: matlab, random

So, I have to simulate the tossing of an unfair die in MATLAB, which has a 20% of probability to show each face between 1 and 4, and 10% of probability to show each face of 5 and 6. I have to generate 5000 random integers, representing the outcomes of tossing the die. I also have to print out the simulated expected value and standard deviation using 5000 repeated trials.

This is the code I wrote in MATLAB:

```
x=randi(6,1,5000); %Generate 5000 random values from 1-6

mean_x = mean(x);    %Find expected value
std_x = std(x);      %Find standard deviation

range_x = [1:6];

bar(range_x, pmf);    %plot the pmf

xlabel('Value of face')
ylabel('Simulated probability mass function')

fprintf('The expected value is %4.2f\n',mean_x);
fprintf('The standard deviation is %4.2f\n', std_x);


function pmf=finitepmf(sx,px,x) %function that finds pmf

    pmf=zeros(size(x(:))); 

    for i=1:length(x) 
        switch x(i)
            case 1 
                px = 0.2;
            case 2 
                px = 0.2;
            case 3 
                px = 0.2;
            case 4 
                px = 0.2;
            case 5 
                px = 0.1;
            case 6 
                px = 0.1;
        end
        pmf(i)= sum(px(find(sx==x(i)))); 
    end

end
```

However, I get  the same `pmf` I would if the die was fair. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's been years since I touched matlab, but for 1. You are calculating your mean and standard deviation on the raw, normal die, not the rigged die.

Comment: Where do you call finitepmf?
Where is sx,px,x passed in?

Comment: When I run your code it says `Undefined function or variable 'pmf'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a much less generic solution than Luis' `randsample`, but it is quite simple and I hope teaches something.

Since your probabilities are all nicely rounded to 10%, you can translate a fair 10-sided die to the unfair 6-sided die of the exercise:

```
map = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6];
```

This `map` will translate an integer 1-10 into an integer 1-6, where 1-4 all have double the chance of being picked than 5-6.

Now draw 5000 random integers 1-10, and map them:

```
x = map(randi(10,1,5000));
```

Compared to a fair 6-sided die:

```
y = randi(6,1,5000);
hx = hist(x,1:6);
hy = hist(y,1:6);
```

I see:

```
hx = [ 988  1029  1022   967   505   489 ]
hy = [ 827   884   833   771   849   836 ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Cris. Now I get it. I had never thought of a solution like that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Statistics (and Machine Learning) Toolbox, use [`randsample`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) with specified weights:

```
result = randsample(6, 5000, true, [.2 .2 .2 .2 .1 .1]);
```

Check:

```
histogram(result)
```

[image]